# Rails pass date object to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date

Here is my code, but it seems to encounter some bugs.

First of all, `@user.birthday` is a Date object and I set it `Tue, 14 Aug 2018` in Rails console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    console.log(new Date(<%= (@user.birthday.to_s) %>));
  });
</script>
```

However, it print `Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:01 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`.

Comment: Look at the generated JavaScript, you'll see `console.log(new Date(2018-08-14))`. You need to quote that string properly or you'll be doing `new Date(1996)`.

Comment: @muistooshort you should probably make that into an answer because 1) that was a good catch and 2) you deserve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a "view source" on that page and look at the JavaScript, you'll see this:

```
console.log(new Date(2018-08-14));
```

which is the same as saying:

```
console.log(new Date(1996));
```

When you give JavaScript's [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) a number, it treats that number as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01:

> `value`
>   Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but consider that most Unix timestamp functions count in seconds).

That's where "Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:01 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)" comes from.

The easiest way to get the right date is to use `#to_json` rather than `#to_s` to build your string and then mark it as "HTML safe" to keep Rails from encoding the double quotes:

```
console.log(new Date(<%= @user.birthday.to_json.html_safe %>));
```

that should give you:

```
console.log(new Date("2018-08-14"));
```

in the generated JavaScript.